# Logstash does not compress the old logs

Tags: apache2, logging, compression

We are using:

```
root@server:~# /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --version
logstash 6.2.4
```

on:

```
root@server:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

with the following `log4j2.properties` configuration:

```
status = error
name = LogstashPropertiesConfig

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = plain_rolling
appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:ls.logs}/logstash-${sys:ls.log.format}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:ls.logs}/logstash-${sys:ls.log.format}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basePath = ${sys:ls.logs}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.age = 7D
appender.rolling.strategy.action.pathConditions.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.pathConditions.glob = logstash-${sys:ls.log.format}-*
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %-.10000m%n

appender.json_rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.json_rolling.name = json_rolling
appender.json_rolling.fileName = ${sys:ls.logs}/logstash-${sys:ls.log.format}.log
appender.json_rolling.filePattern = ${sys:ls.logs}/logstash-${sys:ls.log.format}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
appender.json_rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.json_rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.json_rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.json_rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.json_rolling.layout.type = JSONLayout
appender.json_rolling.layout.compact = true
appender.json_rolling.layout.eventEol = true

rootLogger.level = ${sys:ls.log.level}
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = ${sys:ls.log.format}_rolling
```

According to the [Apache Log4j 2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) for `RollingFileAppender`:

> If the file pattern ends with ".gz", ".zip", ".bz2", ".deflate", ".pack200", or ".xz" the resulting archive will be compressed using the compression scheme that matches the suffix.

We have set our `filePattern` to:

```
${sys:ls.logs}/logstash-${sys:ls.log.format}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz
```

but are finding that the rolled over logs are labelled with the `.gz` extensions, but are in fact, not compressed, e.g.:

```
root@server:~# file /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain-2019-01-17.log.gz 
/var/log/logstash/logstash-plain-2019-01-17.log.gz: ASCII text
```

We have `gzip` installed. What have we missed? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Linux `gzip` program is not required for Log4J 2 to compress log files - it does it using an internal Java implementation. Please note that it will only compress files after they have been rolled - the current file is never compressed. Also, if I understand correctly, Log4J 2 will not compress old files if the application terminated and restarted - files will only be compressed if the trigger condition (7 days in your case) triggered while the application was running. Finally - this is not an Ubuntu specific questions, you may want to try it in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Guss, yes, the current log is `logstash-plain.log` and `/var/log/logstash/logstash-plain-2019-01-17.log.gz` is the archived log. We don't want the current log to be compressed, just the archived ones. Are we to understand that the archived logs will be compressed after 7 days? I would be more than happy to migrate the question to SO but unfortunately, my reputation isn't sufficient for this task.

Comment: @Guss please make sure you know a site's scope before suggesting migration. First, this is completely on topic here, as long as the OP is using Ubuntu. Note that there is essentially _nothing_ that is "specific" to Ubuntu and so [we do not (and cannot) require](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14523/85695) that a question be Ubuntu-specific to be on topic. What's more, this question would be completely off topic on [so] since it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Regarding my own comment from above ("Are we to understand that the archived logs will be compressed after 7 days?"), of course they will not because they will be deleted after 7 days as per `appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.age = 7D`.